# Approach to starting up about 45 services with Docker Swarm Mode

Tags: docker, mode, swarm

I am starting 45 services in Docker Swarm mode across two Ubuntu 16.04 LTS VMs.  Each service is using a different Docker image.  When I perform a 'stack deploy' based on a compose file, all 45 services attempt to start at once.  This, in turn, has a negative effect on the servers and it appears that the majority of effort is around the download and extraction of the Docker images.

Increasing the speed of the disks (SSDs etc) would probably be of benefit here but, assuming hardware changes are not an option, what would be the best approach to starting these services without nuking the VMs?

- Docker 17.06 CE
- Overlay2 Storage Driver
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Many thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: You have 45 services in a single stack file? Can you talk more about your use case?

Comment: Yes @johnharris85 that's correct.  The services monitor for queue items in RabbitMQ and run tasks.  I have other stack files as well but all these services are related so it made sense (in my mind!) to keep them in the same stack.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tried this however you could define 0 replicas in the compose file and write a script that [scale the number of replicas](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_scale/) of the services to 1 slowly.